# Is there a method to apply a mean & variance to existing data?

Tags: probability, statistics

Say I have a set of random and normally distributed set of data, so the mean of the data is 0 and the variance is 1. I want to change the data so that it has variance v and mean m. Is there a way I can do this? Could I possibly plug in my existing values into the Gaussian probability distribution and use the probability as my new data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would the transformation $L(x) = (\sqrt{v})x+m$ do the trick?

$$\operatorname{E}[(\sqrt{v})X+m] = (\sqrt{v})\operatorname{E}[X]+m = m\tag{since $\operatorname{E}[X]=0$}$$
$$\operatorname{Var}[(\sqrt{v})X+m]=(\sqrt{v})^2\operatorname{Var}[X]=v\tag{since $\operatorname{Var}[X]=1$}$$

Generally speaking, applying a linear transformation $L(x)=ax+b$ gets you

$$\operatorname{E}[aX+b] = a\operatorname{E}[X]+b$$
$$\operatorname{Var}[aX+b]=a^2\operatorname{Var}[X]$$

so you could pick $a$ and $b$ to do the job no matter what the initial expectation and variance are.

Also, note that this has nothing to do with the particular distribution, just the values of the expectation and variance.

Comment: When applying an appropriate transformation to my data, I can end up with actual variances and means off by 1. Is it possible to adjust for this error?

Comment: What do you mean, "off by $1$"?

Comment: I will apply this transformation to my data, ie each point is multiplied by the standard deviation and added to the mean, and when I calculate the actual variance and mean I can get say a value of 4.9 when the desired mean is 4. Is this to be expected? (Sorry, I can be a bit slow with these things...)

Answer (score 0):

To change the mean to m just add m to every value of data.mean will change to m.as for variance I don't know if it can be changed.that being said I don't know much about stats.sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multivariable data with mean $\mu$ and covariance $\Sigma$ and you apply the affine transformation $\mathbf{x} \to \mathbf{y} = A\cdot \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}$ to all your data then

$\bar{\mathbf{x}} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\mathbf{x}^{(n)} \to A \cdot \left( \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\mathbf{x}^{(n)} \right) + \mathbf{b} = A\cdot\mu + \mathbf{b}$

In the 1d this shows for $y = ax+b$ then

$\bar{y} = a\bar{x} + b$ or $\mathbb{E}(y) = a\mathbb{E}(x) + b$

You now want to consider the covariance $\hat{\Sigma} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}(\mathbf{y}^{(n)}-\bar{y})(\mathbf{y}^{(n)}-\bar{y})^{\top}$. Plugging in the definition for $\mathbf{y}$ in terms of $\mathbf{x}$,

$\hat{\Sigma}_{\mathbf{y}} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\big( A\cdot \mathbf{x}^{(n)} + \mathbf{b} - (A\cdot\mu+\mathbf{b}) \big)\big( A\cdot \mathbf{x}^{(n)} + \mathbf{b} - (A\cdot\mu+\mathbf{b}) \big)^{\top}$

Notice our $\mathbf{b}$ terms drop out, something we'd expect because the variance is independent of global shifts in the data.

$\hat{\Sigma}_{\mathbf{y}} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\big( A\cdot \mathbf{x}^{(n)} - A\cdot\mu\big)\big( A\cdot \mathbf{x}^{(n)} - A\cdot\mu \big)^{\top} = A\cdot \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\big( \mathbf{x}^{(n)} - \mu\big)\big( \mathbf{x}^{(n)} - \mu\big)^{\top}\cdot A^{\top}$

The summation term is as for the $\mathbf{x}$ case and so we have

$\hat{\Sigma}_{\mathbf{y}} = A \cdot \hat{\Sigma}_{\mathbf{x}}\cdot A^{\top}$

If everything is in 1 dimension this becomes, for $y = ax+b$

$\textrm{Var}(y) = a^{2}\textrm{Var}(x)$

/edit

As MPW says, this is independent of the underlying distribution. It's just that for the Gaussian all you need to know to exactly determine the distribution is the mean and covariance.